# Dynamically updating JSON document in java

Tags: java, json

I have different JSON document. I want to update value against specified path.
How can I achieve this.

Below is the two sample JSON's

```
{
  "A": [
    [
      [
        [
          {
            ".": null
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "M": null
          }
        ]
      ]
    ],
    [
      {
        "A": "Update"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Suppose I have given path : **A[1][0].A** for given path I want to change the value **update** to **updated**

In case of array I'm using indexes. keys are sepeared by **.**
**Note** : JSON document structure is not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [Json Path](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

All you need to do is define configuration and use JSON Path structure to edit a particular node.

```
Configuration config= Configuration.builder()
    .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider())
    .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider())
    .build();

JsonNode newJson=JsonPath.using(config).parse(yourActualJSONString).set("$.A[2].A","UPDATED").json();
System.out.println(newJson.toString());
```

[Refer this for JsonPath syntax.](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

and if you are using Maven to build your project, then here is the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

(or)

[Link to the JSON Path JAR file.](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.0.0/json-path-2.0.0.jar)

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine for key as valid identifier.but it's not working for Key as  [0] or key as . (dot). Can you give me the solution for it ?